# gitlab ci pipeline check if branch or tag set variable

Tags: git, if-statement, pipeline, git-branch, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm running a pipeline that passes the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH as a parameter to a few scripts.  The catch is that if the commit is a tag the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is empty.  Then everything down the pipeline fails.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve this.  The path I've been going down is creating a generic variable for passing into my scripts.  But I need a check to see if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is empty.  I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```py
    check-tag-job:

    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
        variables:
          BRANCH: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
        variables:
          BRANCH: "TAG"
      - when: always
```

My idea was to set $BRANCH to $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH if it's not empty.  If it is empty then set $BRANCH to TAG.  Then I'll deal with that in my scripts.  Just so long as I'm not passing an empty variable into my scripts.

I've tried

```py
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != null'

  
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ null'


    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != ""'

    
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != " "'
```

None of these seems to work.

I did get the following to work but this causes issues with being able to save the $BRANCH variable down the pipeline.

```py
    check-tag-job:

      rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
          when: on_success
    
      variables:
        BRANCH: "TAG"
```

with . . .

```py
    check-branch-job:

        rules:
          - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
            when: on_success
      
          variables:
            BRANCH: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

Seems like there should be an elegant way to resolve this.